# Dynamically loaded javascript doesn't work second time loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, jquery-ui

I am working on a webpage that uses a JQuery UI dialog (in modal mode) to display a form that is dynamically generated using Django. The basic flow is:

- the user clicks a button
- jquery (using AJAX) issues a get request that returns the html for the form which is then used to fill the dialog

  - The html contains a script tag that handles some UI on the form which loads fine and works as expected
- the user than fills out the form and clicks "Done" and the form is submitted.

The issue comes in when the user makes an error on the form. The server responds to the post request (that submits the form) with the original form (including the script) modified to show the errors. This second time the script is loaded it gets a "**Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined (anonymous function)**" The script is exactly the same as before when it worked fine. To be clear throughout this entire process the page is never refreshed.

Here is the gist of the javascript that takes care of the modal:

```
var add_container = $("#add_container");

add_container.dialog({...})

function show_form(form,response_func) {
    add_container.html(form);
    add_container.dialog("open");
    $("#add_form").submit(function (event) {
        return submit_form($(this),response_func);
    });
}

function submit_form(form,response_func) {
    add_container.append('<p>Adding...</p>');
    //this is a trick to upload a file without reloading the page
    form.attr('target','upload_target');
    $('#upload_target').load(function() {
        var response = $('#upload_target').contents().find('body').html();
        add_container.dialog("close");

        resp_obj = $(response)
        if (resp_obj.is('form')) {
            //***this is what reloads the form when there is an error
            show_form(response,response_func);
        } else {
            response_func(resp_obj);
        }

    });
}

$('#add_link').click(add_link);
function add_link() {
    $.get('/add_link', function(data) {
        function add_response(response) {
            //handle successful submission
        }
        show_form(data,add_response);
    });
}

//...more stuff that is not important
```

This is the gist of the html returned from /add_link

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/add_form.js" ></script>
<form id="add_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/add_link/" method="post">
<!-- Dynamically generated form here !-->
</form>
```

The add_form.js is a pretty standard javascript file that uses jQuery. Its starts with $(document).ready(function () {...} ) and the first $ is where the ReferenceError occurs

The form needs to be dynamically generated based on what is clicked so I can't just put everything statically on the page. The script is not dynamically generated so it doesn't necessarily need to be dynamically loaded but I wasn't sure how to keep it in its own file, and also only have it run when the form is loaded. I am open to suggestions of alternative ways to accomplish the same effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to MelanciaUK I realized that when I submitted my form to the iFrame the response was getting sent first to there where the script would run and error because the iFrame is treated as its own page and doesn't have access to jQuery loaded on the main page.

I decided to solve the problem by eliminating the dynamic loading of the add_form script and simply load it when the page loads just like all my other scripts. I created a custom jQuery event (using [.trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)) in order to only have the script run when the add form is opened. This worked exactly the way I wanted it to.

Hope this helps anyone with a similar problem. If you have any questions feel free to ask!

Answer (score 0):

Your form action is pointing to a different relative path to the one containing the jQuery framework script, etc.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/add_form.js" ></script>
<!-- src="/scripts" -->

<form id="add_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/add_link/" method="post">
<!-- action="/add_link" -->
```

To make sure it's loading the framework after the form submission, just use something like the developer tools on your browser and check the head tag for the jQuery script src. Is it still there?

Comment: I double checked and the jQuery script is definitely still there after the form submission. I see the scripts and I can also type '$' in the console and it doesn't give an error. This makes sense because there is no page refresh.

Comment: However your response made me think of an idea. Could the script be executing inside the iFrame that the form is submitting to, since the response is coming back to the iFrame and then the main javascript grabs it? If so, how would I prevent that?